# How can I subtag equations separated by text?

Tags: equations, subequations, tags

I want to subtag two equations separated by text, and refer them together. Is there a chance to achieve that by using `equation` (or `align`) and `subequations`? Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
For the channel to support multiplexing, $A$ should satisfy
\begin{equation}
  A=B
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  B>0.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want the first equation to be tagged with **(1a)**, the second to be tagged with **(1b)**, respectively, and I'd like to refer them together with **(1)** in the following. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `subequations` env from `amsmath` is for.

Illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
For the channel to support multiplexing, $A$ should satisfy
\begin{subequations}
  \label{master}
  \begin{equation}
    A=B \label{first_eq}
  \end{equation}
  and
  \begin{equation}
    B>0. \label{second_eq}
  \end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\eqref{first_eq}
\eqref{second_eq}

\eqref{master}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I usually use subequations in align and don't it can be used like this. Is my question too dumb? If so I'll delete this.

Comment: What exactly do you men by `in align and don't it can be used like this` that does not many any sense